# FUSE: Virtual Directories

Tags: fuse

I am trying to make a FUSE that organizes files based on the extension (.png, .c, ...). I want to display a set of folders in the root directory of the FUSE, each representing a file extension. When someone `cd`s into that folder, it should display all the files with that extension (the user will specify which directory is to be organised while mounting). For example, the output should be like this:

```
mount/$ ls
+c +cpp +png +py
mount/$ cd +c
mount/+c/$ ls
hello.c xyz.c
```

I use `+` to replace the `.` of the extension.

I am using a set implementation and scanning through the desired directory and it's sub directories to find all the file extensions, and then just displaying the contents of the set in readdir.

```
int my_readdir(const char* path, void* buffer, fuse_fill_dir_t filler, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
   filler(buffer,".",NULL,0);
   filler(buffer,"..",NULL,0);
   if(strcmp("/",path)==0)
   {
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<ext_set.length;i++)
     {
       filler(buffer,ext_set.get(i),NULL,0);
     }
   }
}
```

I get the output as shown above, however they are not listed as directories. 
`cd +c` throws `+c: Not a directory` (which it obviously is not).

How do I make them as virtual directories?

Comment: Do you account for `+c` being a directory in `getattr()`?

Comment: No I did not. Thank you!